# Git cvsimport - No CVS folders which causes cvsexportcommit to fail

Tags: git, version-control, cvs

I did a fresh git cvsimport into a new folder, after about 30 minutes it was finally done but it didn't seem to get any of the CVS folders. Since cvsexportcommit looks for the CVS folder in the directory, it fails. My cvsimport command was similar to below:

```
git cvsimport -v -r cvs -d $CVSROOT <module>
```

I then made changed in a work branch, checked out master, performed another cvsimport, merged the work branch onto master but then when running:

```
git cvsexportcommit -w . -u -p -c ORIG_HEAD HEAD
```

The folder is apparently not a CVS repo, (No CVS folders anywhere).

```
is not a CVS checkout at
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `git cvsimport` is a git repository.  The target `-w` of `git cvsexportcommit` is a cvs working copy.  If you want to export back to cvs you need to do `mkdir cvsworking; cd cvsworking; cvs co $CVSROOT <module>` and then from the git dir do your `git cvsexportcommit -w path/to/cvsworking/module -u -p -c ORIG_HEAD HEAD`.  It's not as well integrated as `git-svn`.

Comment: So it's not a good idea to have the CVS and git repos together, but to have something like, path/to/git and path/to/cvs then reference edit the files in the git folder, and reference the cvs folder with -w? Is creating new files still as straight forward as adding them in the git folder and it will be mirror when referncing the cvs folder with -w on the cvsexportcommit?