# git cvsexportcommit pserver fails

Tags: git, cvs, git-cvs

I'm using git and a cvs repo i've trying to follow

[How to export revision history from mercurial or git to cvs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584522/how-to-export-revision-history-from-mercurial-or-git-to-cvs/586225#586225)

except i'm using a -d pserver instead of -w local cvs repo

I've done a git cvsimport and that seems to be good. I am now trying to export a single test change back to the csv repo and it is failing

I've tried the following commands with the following results

command:

```
export $GIT_DIR=~/project/.git
git cvsexportcommit -d :pserver:username:password@someserver/cvsrepo -u -p -c ORIG_HEAD HEAD

Did not find COMMITID in the parents for the commit! at /usr/lib/git-cvsexportcommit line 125.
```

command:

```
export $GIT_DIR=~/project/.git
git cvsexportcommit -d :pserver:username:password@someserver/cvsrepo -u -p -c COMMITID

checking if patch will apply
cvs update: cannot open CVS/Entries for reading: No such file or directory
cvs [update aborted]: no repository
cvs -d :pserver:username:password@someserver/cvsrepo update /path/file.java: 256 at /usr/lib/git-core/git-vcxexportcommit line 436.
```

note: i've tried moving the GIT_DIR up or down a level as well.

Comment: Similar question (and answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240195/git-cvsimport-no-cvs-folders-which-causes-cvsexportcommit-to-fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatley, `git cvsexportcommit` requires the presence of an actual CVS checkout as specified by the `-w` argument.  This is because it simply issues the necessary `cvs commit` command(s) and doesn't interact with the CVS server directly.

Comment: I was worried that was the case. Thanks !